# directly assign .prototype for class inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, inheritance, prototype

We know the classic way to perform inheritance is `Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`, where `Teacher` extends `Person`. However, if I do direct assignment, it seems to work too.

`Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;`

Can I just do this? Now `Teacher` has access to all `Person`'s prototype methods too.

Comment: Now `Teacher.prototype` ***is*** `Person.prototype`. `Teacher`s have access to all `Person`'s prototype methods, but `Person`s also have access to all `Teacher`'s prototype methods, since they both share a single prototype. `Teacher` is not inherting from `Person`, they're just both inherting from the same shared prototype as each other.

Comment: @jfriend00: the `class` syntax doesn't allow two constructors attached to the same prototype, which is what they are doing here. In this case that pattern is wrong, but it has its uses.

Comment: @georg - What the OP is doing here does NOT work.  It ruins the `Person` class by assigning all the `Teacher` methods to the `Person` prototype.  It's not a different object type at all.  It didn't extend the `Person` type - it just modified it.  So, there's NO point in doing what the OP is doing.  I don't know where you get the idea of two constructors on the same object from the above question.  I don't see that anywhere here.

Comment: @jfriend00: see below for a valid use case

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, but it'll mean that when you assign to a property of `Teacher.prototype`, you'll be mutating `Person.prototype`, which is probably not desirable.

```js
// Works:
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}
function Teacher(name) {
  Person.call(this, name);
}
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Teacher.prototype.teaches = function() {
  return true;
}

const p = new Person('bob');
console.log(p.teaches()); // p.teaches is not a function, as expected and desired
```

Compare to

```js
// Bad:
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}
function Teacher(name) {
  Person.call(this, name);
}
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
Teacher.prototype.teaches = function() {
  return true;
}

const p = new Person('bob');
console.log(p.teaches()); // `true`... oops, but bob is not a Teacher, bob is just a Person
```

It's better to use the `Object.create` method so that `Teacher.prototype` is (initially, at least) an *empty object*, free to be mutated, which has an *internal prototype* pointing to `Person.prototype`.

Keep in mind that for *real* code (rather than code being used for a thought experiment for the sake of figuring out the language mechanics), you can avoid much of this hassle and syntax noise by using a `class` and the `extends` keyword:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
class Teacher extends Person {
  teaches() {
    return true;
  }
}
const p = new Person('bob');
console.log(p.teaches()); // p.teaches is not a function, as expected and desired
```

Comment: Well, I'd argue that for something like this, it's better to use the `class` and `extends` syntax than `Object.create()`.

Comment: Instead of standard inheritance method, can I do `Teacher.prototype = {__proto__: Person.prototype}` as well?

Comment: @Maria It looks like that *works*, but manually setting a `__proto__` property is *very* odd. Using `__proto__` at all is also deprecated. Better to avoid it, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this direct assignment of prototypes does make sense, namely when you want the *same* object to be constructed in *different* ways - similarly to overloaded constructors in Java. For example:

```js
function Rectangle(w, h) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
    return this.w * this.h;
}

function RectangleFromCoords(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.w = x2 - x1;
    this.h = y2 - y1;
}

RectangleFromCoords.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;

let a = new Rectangle(20, 10);
console.log(a instanceof Rectangle, a.area())

let b = new RectangleFromCoords(20, 25, 10, 15);
console.log(b instanceof Rectangle, b.area())
```

But in your example, since "Person" and "Teacher" are obviously *different* objects, `Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype` is wrong, because it basically says "every teacher is a person" (which is ok) AND "every person is a teacher" (not ok).

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question at all since the OP clearly intends to inherit.  It's really just a response to a comment someone else besides the OP made.

Comment: Instead of standard inheritance method, can I do `Teacher.prototype = {__proto__: Person.prototype}` as well?

Comment: @Maria: it would be the same as `Object.create(Person.prototype)`, however, using `__proto__` is not recommended.